# Big o of insertion sort algorithm: iterative and recursive

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, insertion-sort

Here I have two insertion sort algorithms. I am having trouble finding out the big O of these two forms of insertion sort. I have an iterative form and a recursive form. Am I wrong to say the iterative form is n^2 and the recursive form is n^2. If I am wrong what are they and why? How did you come to that answer?

```
  public void iterativeSort(int[] list) {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            count++;
            int temp = list[i];
            int j;

            for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp < list[j]; j--) {
                list[j + 1] = list[j];
            }

            list[j + 1] = temp;
            finish += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }

    }

    public static void recursiveSort(int array[], int n, int j) {
        finish += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (j < n) {

            int i;
            count++;
            int temp = array[j];

            for (i = j; i > 0 && array[i - 1] > temp; i--) {
                array[i] = array[i - 1];
            }

            array[i] = temp;

            recursiveSort(array, n, j + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Relevant and perhaps a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right that both implementations take `O(n^2)` time. You cannot possibly reduce the running time of an algorithm by switching from recursive to iterative implementation or vice versa. This does **not** hold for the space usage though.

How can you determine that the running time is `O(n^2)`. It is easier and more obvious for the iterative solution. In general, when you have nested `for`-loops without any specific break conditions and you are running through a fraction of the elements that is linear, the running time is quadratic. Let's analyze it further. How many times will the condition in `for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)` evaluate to `true`? The answer is `n-1`, since you go from the second element until the end. For example if `n=5`, the condition will be `true` for `i = 1, 2, 3, 4` (due to 0-based indexing), exactly `n-1` times, which in this example means 4. Now how many times will the inner loop condition evaluate to `true`? On the first run it will get executed once, because `i = 1` and `j = 0` and after one iteration `j` will be `-1` which will break the condition. On the second iteration it will get executed twice, on the third three times etc, up to `n - 1` times. So what we basically have is the sum `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (n - 1)` which you can easily prove that is equal to `(n-1)n/2)`. Since you drop constants in big-O, the running time is `O(n^2)`.

Now the analysis of the second implementation may appear a bit more intricate because of the recursion, but it is actually not very different. The logic for the inner loop, `for (i = j; i > 0 && array[i - 1] > temp; i--)`, is pretty much the same, because it gets executed once, when `j = 1`, twice when `j = 2` etc. How many times will we call the method recursively? Again `n - 1` times, because the first call is `j = 1` and therefore `j < n` (assuming that n is large), which calls then `recursiveSort(array, n, j + 1);`. Now `j = 2` is again smaller than `n`, so we will call the function recursively until `j == n`, so exactly `n - 1` times. Given that the inner loop is nested in `O(n)`, we get the same number of iterations, namely `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + ( n-1 )` resulting in `O(n^2)` again.

So we informally proved that the two algorithms have the same asymptotic running time. Can we consider them equivalent in this case? **No**. This is because each recursive call reserves additional space on the stack, meaning that the recursive solution takes `O(n)` space, whereas the iterative one `O(1)`. In that sense we may say that the iterative solution is better, which is usually the case, but the recursive one may be more readable(which is not the case here).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think it helped me make sense of the problem.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Big-O is something that beginners often struggle with, so don't get intimidated if you don't understand everything in detail. I tried to be as precise as possible, but in fact you need some time to actually get used to it and truly understand it.